# Drag and drop JS

Tags: javascript, python, css, drag-n-drop

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.imageUpload = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            outputHandler: function() {}, // Callback function for processing output. Parameter is image source in base64 format
            onBeforeUpload: function() {},// Callback function called before upload processing
            onAfterUpload: function() {},   // Callback function called after upload processing
            maxUpload: 113,             // Max number of image files allowed to be uploaded.
            errorMsg: 'Error: The file you just uploaded is not an image!',
            trigger: 'click',           // possible values: "click", "dblclick" or null
            errorContainer: null,       // Container for error message
            enableCliboardCapture: true, // Enable clipboard capturing
            enableDebug: true           // enable debugging output in console
        }, options );

        var $this = $(this), dragging = false, pasting = false;

        var $uploadField = $('<input type="file" style="display:none" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*, .gif, .png, .jpg" />');

        // Create capture area for Mozilla & IE
        var $contentEditable = $('<div contenteditable="true" style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;top:-20px;width:0;height:0;" />');


        // Error display
        var errorHandler = function(error) {
            if (error && settings.errorContainer !== null) {
                settings.errorContainer.html(settings.errorMsg).fadeIn(1000,function() {
                    $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
                });
            }
        };

        var readFile = function(file) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            $(reader).on('load', file, function(e){

                var returnValue = {
                    name: (e.data.name ? e.data.name :'CB_Image_' + (+new Date()) + getFileExtension(e.target.result)),
                    type: (e.data.type ? e.data.type : getFileType(e.target.result)),
                    size: (e.data.size ? e.data.size : 'n/a'),
                    imgSrc: e.target.result
                };

                // Execute outputHandler callback function if available
                $.isFunction(settings.outputHandler) && settings.outputHandler.call(this, returnValue);
                // Execute onAfterUpload callback function if available
                $.isFunction(settings.onAfterUpload) && settings.onAfterUpload.call(this);
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        // Upload processing
        var processUpload = function(files, originalEvent) {
            var error = false, imageFound = false, count = 0;
            console.log(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
            if (files !== null) {

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (files[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) {
                         //not image
                        error = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (count == settings.maxUpload) break; // Max reached
                    count++;
                    imageFound = true;

                    // Webkit clipboard data needs data converted through getAsFile()
                    var blob = (typeof originalEvent !== 'undefined' && !originalEvent.msConvertURL) ? files[i].getAsFile() : files[i];
                    
                    readFile(blob);
                }
                if (!imageFound) {
                    // Execute onAfterUpload callback function if available
                    $.isFunction(settings.onAfterUpload) && settings.onAfterUpload.call(this);
                }
                errorHandler(error);
            }
        };

        // Paste handler
        var pasteHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
            // Remove existing Mozilla "input" event handler
            $contentEditable.off('input',mozillaCaptureFunc);

            // Execute onBeforeUpload callback function if available
            $.isFunction(settings.onBeforeUpload) && settings.onBeforeUpload.call(this);

            var clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
            if (clipboardData === false || clipboardData === undefined) {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
                // empty
                // Execute onAfterUpload callback function if available
                $.isFunction(settings.onAfterUpload) && settings.onAfterUpload.call(this);
                pasting = false;
                return false;
            }

            var files = clipboardData.items || clipboardData.files;

            // No Items or files, so either nothing in clipboard or Mozilla browser
            if (files.length === 0) {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
                // Enable "input" event handler for Mozilla, and set focus
                $contentEditable.on('input',mozillaCaptureFunc).focus();
            }
            else {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
                pasting = false;
                processUpload(files, e.originalEvent);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        };

        // Alternate triggering metod for clipboard capturing, required for IE & Mozilla
        var keydownHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            if (!pasting && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.which == 86) {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
                pasting = true;
                $contentEditable.focus();
            }
        };

        // Alternative to css :hover, adding class "dropzonehover" to body tag.
        var mouseenterHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!$('body').hasClass('dragging')) $('body').addClass('dropzonehover');
        };
        var mouseleaveHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').removeClass('dropzonehover');
        };

        // Submit handler to trigger hidden 'input type="file"' upload field
        var submitFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $uploadField.trigger('click');
        };
        // File upload handler
        var uploadFunc = function(e) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
            processUpload(e.target.files);

        };
        // "drop" handler
        var dropHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').removeClass('dragging dragover');
            dragging = false;
            
            processUpload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

        };
        // General handler for preventing propragation and default action
        var preventHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };
        // Dragover handler for preventing propragation and default action
        var preventDragoverHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
            try {
                // IE won't allow setting of effectAllowed
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'none';
               } catch(err) {}
        };
        // "dragover" handler
        var dragoverHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            try {
                // IE won't allow setting of effectAllowed
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copyMove';
               } catch(err) {}
        };
        // "dragenter" handler, adding class "dragover" to body tag.
        var dragenterHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').addClass('dragover');
        };
        // "dragleave" handler, removing class "dragover" from body tag.
        var dragleaveHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').removeClass('dragover');
        };

        // Pseudo "dragstart" handler, adding class "dragging" to body tag.
        var dragstartHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (!$('body').hasClass('dragging') && !dragging) {
                $('body').addClass('dragging');
                dragging = true;
            }
        };
        // Pseudo "dragend" handler, removing class "dragging" from body tag.
        var dragendHandlerFunc = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($('body').hasClass('dragging') && dragging) {
                $('body').removeClass('dragging');
                dragging = false;
            }
        };

        // Enable clipboard capturing
        if (settings.enableCliboardCapture) {
            $contentEditable.appendTo('body').focus();
            $(window).on({
                keydown: keydownHandlerFunc, // IE & Mozilla
                paste: pasteHandlerFunc
            });
        }

        // Enable file requester upload
        if (settings.trigger !== null) {
            $uploadField.on('change',uploadFunc).appendTo('body').blur();
            $this.on(settings.trigger, submitFunc);
        }
        // Enable drag and drop upload
        $this.on({
            dragenter: dragenterHandlerFunc,
            dragleave: dragleaveHandlerFunc,
            dragover: dragoverHandlerFunc,
            drop: dropHandlerFunc,
            mouseenter: mouseenterHandlerFunc,
            mouseleave: mouseleaveHandlerFunc
        });
        // Prevent dropping outside droparea
        // Since dragstart and dragend is not triggered when dragging local files,
        // the "html" tag is used as fake "triggers" (Using "body" tag has problems)
        $('html').on({
            dragbetterenter: dragstartHandlerFunc,
            dragbetterleave: dragendHandlerFunc,
            dragover: preventDragoverHandlerFunc,
            drag: preventHandlerFunc,
            drop: preventHandlerFunc
        });
        // chainable
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Shared callback handler for processing output
    var outputHandlerFunc = function(imgObj) {

        var sizeInKB = function(bytes) {return (typeof bytes == 'number') ? (bytes/1024).toFixed(2) + 'Kb' : bytes;};

        var getThumbnail = function(original, maxWidth, maxHeight, upscale) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), width, height;
            if (original.width<maxWidth && original.height<maxHeight && upscale == undefined) {
                width = original.width;
                height = original.height;

            }
            else {
                width = maxWidth;
                height = parseInt(original.height*(maxWidth/original.width));
                if (height>maxHeight) {
                    height = maxHeight;
                    width = parseInt(original.width*(maxHeight/original.height));
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height);
            $(canvas).attr('title','Original size: ' + original.width + 'x' + original.height);
            return canvas;
        }



        $(new Image()).on('load', function(e) {

            var $wrapper = $('<li class="new-item"><div class="list-content"><span class="preview"></span><span class="type">' + imgObj.name + '<br>' + (e.target.width + '&times;' + e.target.height) + '<br>' + sizeInKB(imgObj.size) + '</span><span class="name"><span class="imagedelete" title="Remove image"></span><span class="button"<button>рассчитать</button></span>'  +'</span><span class="options"><span class="imagedelete" title="Remove image"></span><span class="options"></span></div></li>').appendTo('#output ul');
            $('.button',$wrapper).one('click',function(e) {console.log('')});
            $('.imagedelete',$wrapper).one('click',function(e) {
                $wrapper.toggleClass('new-item').addClass('removed-item');
                $wrapper.one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e) {
                    $wrapper.remove();
                });
            });
            
            var thumb = getThumbnail(e.target,50,50);
            var $link = $('<a rel="fancybox">').attr({
                target:"_blank",
                href: imgObj.imgSrc
            }).append(thumb).appendTo($('.preview', $wrapper));
            
        }).attr('src',imgObj.imgSrc);

    }

    $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox();

    var fileReaderAvailable = (typeof FileReader !== "undefined");
    var clipBoardAvailable = (window.clipboardData !== false);
    var pasteAvailable = Boolean(clipBoardAvailable & fileReaderAvailable & !eval('/*@cc_on !@*/false'));

    if (fileReaderAvailable) {

        // Enable drop area upload
        $('#dropzone').imageUpload({
            errorContainer: $('span','#errormessages'),
            trigger: 'dblclick',
            enableCliboardCapture: pasteAvailable,
            onBeforeUpload: function() {$('body').css('background-color','green');},
            onAfterUpload: function() {$('body').css('background-color','#eee');},
            outputHandler:outputHandlerFunc
        })

        $('#dropzone').prev('#textbox-wrapper').find('#textbox').append('<p class="large">Drag and Drop<br>Image File here</p><p class="small">Doubleclick<br>for file requester</p>');
    }
    else {
        $('body').addClass('nofilereader');
    }

    if (!pasteAvailable) {
        $('body').addClass('nopaste');
    }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font: normal 11px arial;
}

kbd {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 1px 0 #eee, 0 2px 0 2px #ccc, 0 2px 0 3px #444;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 6px 3px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}

#errormessages {
  font: bold 13px Arial;
  color: #DD3030;
  min-height: 32px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropzone-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 6px dotted #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#dropzone-wrapper #dropzone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font: bold 20px Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.42);
}

#dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p.small {
  color: #777;
  font: bold 12px Arial;
}

/* Replacement for :hover */
.dropzonehover #dropzone-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(220, 109, 10, 0.2);
  border-color: #dc6d0a;
}

.dragover #dropzone-wrapper {
  background-color: #9bf79b;
  border-color: #006d0a;
}

.dropzonehover #dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p.small {
  color: #dc6d0a;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.dropzonehover #dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p.large {
  font-size: 0px;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.dragging #dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p.small {
  font-size: 0px;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.dragging #dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p.large {
  color: green;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.dragover #dropzone-wrapper #textbox-wrapper #textbox p.small {
  color: red;
}

.dragging #dropzone-wrapper {
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-animation: greenPulse 1.5s infinite;
          animation: greenPulse 1.5s infinite;
}

#output canvas {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -99998;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.dragging #overlay {
  z-index: 99998;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes greenPulse {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #08FF00, 0 0 6px #fff;
    border-color: #aaa;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 22px #0FBC09, 0 0 30px #fff;
    border-color: #0FBC09;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #08FF00, 0 0 6px #fff;
    border-color: #aaa;
  }
}

@keyframes greenPulse {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #08FF00, 0 0 6px #fff;
    border-color: #aaa;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 22px #0FBC09, 0 0 30px #fff;
    border-color: #0FBC09;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #08FF00, 0 0 6px #fff;
    border-color: #aaa;
  }
}
#helpbutton {
  background: #eee;
  background: linear-gradient(#eee, #e2e2e2);
  border: solid 1px #d0d0d0;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #b2b1b1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f5f5f5;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fafafa;
}

#helpbutton:hover {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  background: linear-gradient(#e4e4e4, #ededed);
  border: solid 1px #c2c2c2;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #b2b1b1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #efefef;
}

#helpbutton #helpscreen {
  color: #111;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  background: #ffff88;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  font: normal 11px arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#helpbutton:active #helpscreen, #helpbutton #helpscreen:hover {
  width: 380px;
  height: 280px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nopaste #helpbutton, .nofilereader #dropzone-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

#output ul {
  max-width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#output ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-content {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.list-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.list-content span.preview {
  width: 55px;
}

.list-content span.type {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

.list-content span.name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.list-content span.options {
  width: 30px;
}


.list-content span.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-position: -106px 0px;
}

.list-content span.options .imagedelete {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAQCAYAAAB3AH1ZAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyNJREFUeNrEVGtIU2EYfs7Ojh6nc+Jt5WWmk7w3cKnlDamQLqJIvyv6UQT9CIkiNPwTiIYQQqaFRf2MCCmQCgwKzB+GJEYpXipNzUuunO54tp1L36YbZ8tVrKAX3vN9H9/7vN9z3hslyzL+p6g9m9aecerl4GQzraKyE2Ii0sNYJpahVVpBkiiOd1ptnGN53mKb5BzCu9w0fX3Hmb2C0lGweC+BZ/0jT29dqK5kGGCFByyrPJa+r2NxxQabzRHLO5yxpkxVRkq89nBn98AeAilXEggWr/I4yEuNM+k0wLodsNsF8EQ5uxPcuhM2sjoEERKxi4tiYUrX5/iHMli8NwITM8sjY8vQR6pF8qGRHBUOIVEDSYyGKFNYIw7nljlMza9geGJh2J9AsHgvgeI8Q8W8VUTn23WoJCcoyQ7JwcO6asWKdQ2zixbMflnAqSP52Je/o8KfQLB4ldJJaQoNcxKNjG0sEnU0QtQUzEY9puaWUFVmBs9ZUVNuCljRgfAz81+9+KMVpq27wCUiSZJAlKXJnqERFqJGlDYUrlZl2VBiQUEguQwk/vjjRbEoMYaj/mA1Xk/bkR99CMXJKuhkw9YEiH+3yG6V3Q975sQfzQsFvjJDg93JLCa7mgFJQsHpehQYMjHW1oCI+ATAcPYAMev1JfC3M0mBdz3+4fZVfLzTsvGn4VoItlVM37/hPnNTE+ezLl3zI/APxZUOSs14z+Ptjb7BomkpYAqCFgV+cIZH4Yk6MFodRlsvuihtlj2DgptPoMsx9/9MwJ3rDd3yr0Txt1ny4DXMBhu7ZdE3N+RS4Fa9dH3aMIxELEajQnwEBae4UdESWV0TzUmqPz01FbqwwFnz4BN1FHK3h5KCu7xZA5KCgIA352pdd1d8CAx9+ma83j2MmrxQlKaxyDeEo8gYiaSYEHTUVaGYtNODxlq8GHiP3qHPO/0fV+KLUljYBRmaZKP3vrDrOcztPZsnGvzCTJM7DMr2Otb2qjgnSfvqVyHuH10qe9ywv2+rOyW+JEuPsmw9Zh/dg0zaMKn2JPpGFhDysGWA5Sy9u5ruNrjsfggwANaIwN5Hg9AjAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.list-content span.options .imagedelete:hover {
  background-position: -16px 0px;
}

#output .removed-item {
  -webkit-animation: removed-item-animation 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.55, -0.04, 0.91, 0.94) forwards;
          animation: removed-item-animation 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.55, -0.04, 0.91, 0.94) forwards;
}

#output .new-item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: openspace 0.6s ease forwards, new-item-animation 0.3s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.32, 1.07) forwards;
          animation: openspace 0.6s ease forwards, new-item-animation 0.3s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.32, 1.07) forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openspace {
  to {
    height: auto;
  }
}

@keyframes openspace {
  to {
    height: auto;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes removed-item-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes removed-item-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes new-item-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes new-item-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CNN</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div style="float: left;width:240px;">
    <div id="dropzone-wrapper">
        <div id="textbox-wrapper"><div id=textbox></div></div>
        <div id="dropzone"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="errormessages"><span style="display: none;"></span></div>

    <div id="overlay"></div>

    <div id="helpbutton">
        <span>Paste Help</span>
        <div id="helpscreen">
            <p><strong>PC:</strong> Capture screen to clipboard: <kbd>PrtScr</kbd></p>
            <p><strong>PC:</strong> Insert screenshot: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd></p>
            <hr />
            <!--<p>Capture screen to clipboard <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd></p>-->
            <p><strong>Mac:</strong> Capture screen to clipboard: <kbd>&#8984;</kbd> + <kbd>&#8679;</kbd> + <kbd>&#8963;</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd></p>
            <p><strong>Mac:</strong> Insert screenshot: <kbd>&#8984;</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd></p>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div style="float: left;">
    <br /><br />
    <h3>Preview:</h3>
    <div id="output"><ul></ul></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.dragbetter@0.1.4/jquery.dragbetter.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Всем привет, такой вопрос: сделал нейросеть на python, всегда пользовался консолью, а тут решил визуализировать. C js и ccs/html дел особо не имел, скачал код для drag and drop. Идея такая, закидываю снимки для классификации, нажимаю на кнопку, получаю результат. Все это дело я свяжу с ell, у меня уже почти все готово, единственный вопрос: как получить полный путь до файла с картинкой? У меня только имя и все, два часа мучался)) не знаю что делать, помогите)))

Comment: Код не смотрел. Не понятно, при чем  здесь d&d . У вас картинки не отображаются?

Comment: отображаются, мне полные пути нужно получить, например при нажатие на клавишу